# ros-fuerte cannot find opencv package

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have installed ros-fuerte-desktop-full. I am trying to built a package that contains opencv code, but I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot specify link libraries for target "MatObjects" which is not built by this project.
```

I have added following to CMakeLists.txt

```
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
target_link_libraries(MatObjects ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Here is the output of some flags:

```
#echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/pkgconfig
```

This path contains opencv.pc

```
#pkg-config --cflags opencv
-I/opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv -I/opt/ros/fuerte/include

#pkg-config --libs opencv
-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab
```

I have also tried to run the code on Geany using g++ with `pkg-config --cflags opencv` but it says `Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path` when it is there.

Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139986/ros-fuerte-cannot-find-opencv-package/) by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2014-03-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With rosmake, unlike catkin, you typically do not have to find_package and target_link_libraries opencv yourself. The only thing you have to do for developing against OpenCV with ros fuerte and rosbuild is to add a depend package to your manifest.xml:

```
  <depend package="opencv2"/>
```

Add this to your manifest.xml, remove

```
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
target_link_libraries(MatObjects ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

from CMakeLists.txt, and tell me if it worked;)

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aparraga](https://answers.ros.org/users/13351/aparraga/) on 2014-03-14**:
I'm in agreement

**Comment by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on 2014-03-14**:
Thanks sir. It worked. I am a bit surprised. I had ros-fuerte installed (before I refreshed ubuntu and installed fuerte again) and my previous method (linking libraries in CMakeLists.txt) was working. Has it changed recently?

**Comment by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on 2014-03-14**:
I also use PCL libraries, so now I have to do the same for PCL libraries too? Previously, I was linking PCL libraries in CMakeLists.txt too and it was working.

**Comment by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on 2014-03-14**:
One more thing: I use Geany and give build command: g++ "%f" `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -o "%e". Previously it was working but not now. It says opencv.pc is not in the PKG_CONFIG path. I checked the path and opencv.pc is there. Any clue?

**Comment by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on 2014-03-14**:
Geany Error: Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found